# How many VM's I can create and share CPU cores on 24 core CPU?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, ubuntu-server, core

I have a server that has 2 (CPU) - 24 cores. Is there a limit how many VM's I can create and assign CPU's?

Ex: Is there a limit that, I can only create 6 VM's that have 4 CPUs each? or 12 VM's with 2 CPU each? (Considering max 24 core available? )

I'm running the setup on Ubuntu Server 14.04 with KVM.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/504626/best-practice-vcpus-per-physical-core

Comment: No, there isn't really a limit, and you can go beyond the number of cores available. Hypervisors like VMWare aggregate CPU capacity, and divide it up by hrtz, so doesn't really assign a physical core to a VM. it timeslices execution time between whatever threads need the time, up to the quota'd frequency. as you add more guests, more processes will want execution capacity though. beware assigning too many cores to a guest. when a 4-cpu guest is running VMWare at least will wait until it can get time on 4 cores (called "Processor Ready Time") which can really cripple throughput.

Comment: Frank Thomas, You have answered my question, however you have answered it as comment to my question and because of that I dont see a close button to my question! @moderators please help me! I have received my correct answer but unable to close it!